# Shared folder accessible from Windows 11 but not from Windows 10

Tags: network-share, windows-10, windows-server-2022, windows-11

I have a shared folder on  Windows Server 2022 that I can access from my Windows 11 computers.

Accessing it from a Windows 10 computer fails with error code 0x80004005.

I've explored troubleshooting steps such as connecting with 'net use', enabling and disabling SMB 1.0. I ensured that I logged in with the same account on both the Windows 10 and Windows 11 computers, testing also with different accounts as well. I also examined network traffic using Wireshark, but my limited expertise prevents me from conducting a thorough analysis. Additionally, I attempted to temporarily disable the server's firewall without success. Ping works. Also, I have access to other share from other server.

I'm uncertain about the next steps to resolve this issue. Does anyone have insights or suggestions?

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score -2):

For anyone who's interested, I didn't know why but I should activate smb 1.0 on the 2022 server, now everything works.

Comment: Windows 10 does not require SMB1.

Comment: Then idk what I can do, because it was the problem...